# In Sketch, is it possible to copy a symbol and paste an instance?

Tags: sketch-app, symbols, copy-and-paste

I have a very large and complicated file with hundreds and hundreds of symbols all of which are used and reused over and over with slight variations.

My naming schema is about as good as I can get it, but sometimes I want to reuse a symbol in a totally different part of the site, and it's very hard to tell which version is which in the tiny little thumbnails in the “Insert” menu.

Is there a way to go into the symbols page, pick which symbol I want, copy it, then go back to the original and paste an instance of the symbol? If I just use copy and paste, it pastes the symbol, not an instance of it. Is there any other way to achieve this? Essentially, make my selection on the symbols page and get it onto the main page without having to memorize the full naming path and recall it from the main page?

Answer (score 0):

did you try runner plugin?
You Can see them a little larger...

[image]